# How to filter through boolean with getProgramAccounts?

Tags: getprogramaccounts

I know how to filter a `getProgramAccounts` with a publicKey but I am struggling to do it with a boolean.

I tried:

```
{
  memcmp: {
    offset: 8 + 4,
    bytes: false,
  },
},
```

It gives me an error, should I do some conversion on the "false" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A boolean is typically stored as one byte, where 0 is false, and 1 is true, so you can do:

```
{
  memcmp: {
    offset: 8 + 4,
    bytes: '1',
  },
},
```

No, this isn't a typo, the byte `[0]` is encoded as the string `'1'` in base58.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me. Just tried the same but it gives me the error.

`SolanaJSONRPCError: failed to get accounts owned by program: Invalid param: Base58DecodeError(InvalidCharacter { character: '0', index: 0 })`

Comment: `0` is an invalid base58 character, so try `1`

Comment: okay. it worked. thanks very much. but it always returns items with `false`, how to filter items with `true` ?

Comment: `2`. Be sure to read more about how base58 encoding works or use a converter if you ever need to: https://appdevtools.com/base58-encoder-decoder

Comment: Thank you. It worked!
Can I set the offset something like this `offset: (8 + 4) + 8` for the filter by next boolean field?

Comment: Yep, you can use as many filters as you want, and you'll get accounts that satisfy all of them